# MySQL: Count related records through a join table, where source can have multiple entries with the same ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this MySQL query.  I've broken it down into its components as much as I can below.  I've obfuscated the table names just for kicks (and giggles!) but the structure is the same.

## Goal

We want to count the number of `puppies` that are linked to a `kennel`

## Situation

- A `kennel` has `kennel_entries` via a `kennel_entry.kennel_id`
- A `puppy` belongs to a `kennel_entry` via a polymorphic join table (e.g. `relationship.to_id = 123` `relationship.to_model = "puppy"`, `relationship.from_id = 111`, and `relationship.from_model = "kennel_entry"`)
- We've got multiple `kennels` with the same `id`, but different `revision_id`s (this is the part that makes it confusing for me)

The way it is, if there are multiple revisions of the same `kennel`, I get bloated `puppy` counts... Here's the SQL I'm working with:

```
SELECT
  kennel.id,
  COUNT(puppy.id) puppy_count
FROM kennel
JOIN relationship
  ON kennel.id = relationship.from_id AND (SELECT MAX(kennel.revision_id))
JOIN puppy
  ON puppy.id = relationship.to_id
JOIN kennel_entry
  ON kennel.id = kennel_entry.review_id
WHERE relationship.from_model = 'kennel'
AND relationship.to_model = 'puppy'
AND puppy.status = 2
AND kennel_entry.status = 3
GROUP BY kennel.id
```

The above query ALMOST works... but it seems to be reporting some odd numbers in some cases.  Sometimes I get double or triple the correct counts.  I'm not sure what's going on.

MySQL version: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.37, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2`

-- edit --

Here's my latest attempt, it's closer but it doesn't account for `kennel_entry.status = 3`:

```
SELECT
  kennel.id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT puppy.id) puppy_count
FROM kennel
JOIN relationship
  ON kennel.id = relationship.from_id
JOIN puppy
  ON puppy.id = relationship.to_id
JOIN kennel_entry
  ON kennel.id = kennel_entry.review_id
WHERE relationship.from_model = 'kennel'
AND relationship.to_model = 'puppy'
AND puppy.status = 2
AND kennel_entry.status = 3
GROUP BY kennel.id
```

Comment: What is `ON kennel.id = relationship.from_id AND (SELECT MAX(kennel.revision_id))` supposed to achieve?

Comment: I was futzing around with it and just wanted to show my current state of affairs.  It is unnecessary if it doesn't actually contribute.  I may have been confusing myself.

Comment: That was **the** problem. That statement was producing a partial Cartesian product.  The only reason it worked at all is that `MySQL` understands `0 and 1` as `false and true`.

Comment: Cool, didn't know that was possible!  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: I think I may have confused everyone by adding the MAX function. That's not what is important... it was just an experiment. I think what I really want is DISTINCT video.id, but that still isn't working... That's why I put the "Goal" section. It doesn't matter what query is used as long as the goal is achieved. Sorry for any confusion!  I'm editing the question with my latest attempt.

Answer (score 2):

To only count kennels having the maximum `revision_id` for every `id`, add the following join

```
JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(revision_id) max_revision_id
        FROM kennel GROUP BY id) t1 
  ON t1.id = kennel.id AND t1.max_revision_id = kennel.revision_id
```

Comment: Sorry, I think the `MAX` was misleading... I really just want to count the puppies in each kennel.... `MAX` isn't important.  I tried `DISTINCT puppy.id` and that was closer, but doesn't account for the `kennel_entry.status`

Answer (score 0):

Here would be a solution formatted as a common table expression.

```
WITH LastRev as (
  SELECT id, MAX(k.revision_id) max_rev_id
  FROM kennel k
  GROUP BY k.id)
SELECT
  kennel.id,
  COUNT(puppy.id) puppy_count
FROM kennel
JOIN LastRev lr on kennel.id = lr.id and kennel.revision_id = lr.max_rev_id
JOIN relationship
  ON kennel.id = relationship.from_id
JOIN puppy
  ON puppy.id = relationship.to_id
JOIN kennel_entry
  ON kennel.id = kennel_entry.review_id
WHERE relationship.from_model = 'kennel'
AND relationship.to_model = 'puppy'
AND puppy.status = 2
AND kennel_entry.status = 3
GROUP BY kennel.id
```